# Xamarin Forms. Размер картинки кнопки

Tags: изображения, xamarin, button, xamarin.forms

Есть кнопка. На ней картинка. Картинка заведомо большего размера чем надо. Как сделать так, чтобы картинка уменьшалась или увеличивалась до размера кнопки?

Есть вот такой код.

````
        <Button Text="Протокол агронома" ImageSource ="ProtocolImage.png"  Style="{StaticResource buttonStyle}"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = .1}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = .9}"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor = .05}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor = .3}"
            ContentLayout="Left, -300"
/>
    </RelativeLayout>```
````

Comment: Может, `HeightRequest` и `WidthRequest` явно задать поможет?

Comment: Не сработало, по ходу только создавать иконки под каждое возможное разрешение